# Colorbar uses different cmap than plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, imshow

I am trying to plot a colorbar, but the colorbar follows a different cmap. I think it follows cmap = veridis?

When I change the cmap colorscale, only the graph color changes and not the colorbar.

How can this be overcome?

In the section below my code and plot.

```
# Create canvas
cvs = ds.Canvas(x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range, plot_height=h, plot_width=w)

# Heatmap
aggs = cvs.line(df_reshaped, 'x', 'y', ds.count())
heatmap_img = tfnc.Image(tfnc.shade(aggs, cmap=plt.cm.magma))

# plot & colorbar
im = ax.imshow(heatmap_img.to_pil(), aspect='auto')

cbar = fig.colorbar(im, fraction=0.03, pad=0.05, ticks=[0, 250], ax=ax)
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(['Low', 'High'],fontsize=20)
cbar.set_label('Agg. series count', labelpad=-25,fontsize=20)
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!
Bram

Comment: I don't know what a `tfnc.Image` is, or most of the rest of your code, because you have not made a self contained example.  However, `imshow` will ignore the colormap if the data is a 3xMxN array because you are supplying the RGB information to imshow rather than matplotlib doing a colormapping.  You can fake the colorbar in various ways, perhaps most easily by `imshow(cmap='plasma', vmin=suitablemin, vmax=suitablemax)`.  The cmap will be ignored for the image, but will still be applicable to the colorbar.